# What happens to questions with bounty when OP was suspended for more than 8 days?

Tags: support, bounty, account-suspension

What  happens to questions with bounty when OP was suspended for more than 8 days?

Will the bounty be lost? or will be refunded? or in case someone answers will be awarded somehow?

Thank you

Comment: Some related posts on [meta.se]: [Will bounty rolled back if user removed or suspended?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/224482) and [Suspended user cannot award bounty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100050).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A suspended user cannot award the bounty. See
[Will bounty rolled back if user removed or suspended?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224482/will-bounty-rolled-back-if-user-removed-or-suspended)

Thus, what will happen is that same as if the user just would not show up during the relevant period of time. Roughly, a reduced bounty will be automatically awarded based on score.

From [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

> Approximately 24 hours after the end of the bounty period (once the grace period ends), if the bounty starter has not manually awarded the bounty, the bounty may be awarded automatically.
> If the author offered the bounty, and accepted an answer that was posted after the bounty was started, that answer is awarded the full bounty.
> Otherwise, either all or half of the bounty will be awarded to the highest-scored answer among those which meet all of the following:
>
> - They were posted after the bounty was started, and
> - They have a score of at least 2 (at the time the automatic awarding takes place), and
> - They were not written by the bounty starter.
>
> If the chosen answer was accepted by the question owner, it will receive the full bounty. Otherwise, it will receive half the bounty. If two eligible answers have the same score, the older answer is chosen.
> If no answer meets any of the above two criteria, the bounty is not awarded to any answer, and is not refunded to the bounty starter.